# Does fork() in linux copy all the parent's memory pages to the child?

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system

I read about copy on write but I don't understand it. Does this mean that the memory pages are not copied until the child process has written something?

Comment: Until de child process or the parent process write something to the shared pages. Or until the child or the parent does `exec()`...

Comment: A page is not copied until parent or child modified something in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as no write operation is performed on a child's memory page, they are identical to a parent's memory page to a user process. Therefore, as long as the page is not written to, it can be used for both the parent and child.

If, however, a write operation is performed the parent's and child's versions differ. At this point, the parent's page is copied and assigned to the child in place of the parent page. This copy is called "copy on write" because the copy is performed when the page is written to.

Note that "copy on write" is just an optimization of the `fork`ing operation. A naive implementation simply duplicates the pages of the parent for the child instantly. By noticing that pages not yet written to do not require that duplication, that copy is postponed until the child actually writes something (the term "laziness" is often used for that delay), which might not happen at all.